# Getting Custom Fields from WordPress JSON API

Tags: custom-field, plugin-json-api

I'm using the plugin (https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API) to get JSON Data from WordPress, but I'm stuck on something, I've a custom post type, events, with which many custom fields is attached to, such as datefrom, dateto, latitude, longitude.

This URL http://www.domainname.com/wp-json/posts?type=events&lang=fr is properly returning me the events, however, i'm not getting any of the custom fields, any help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Custom fields are Post Meta items,  so you will need to retrieve these separately,  reading the documentation suggests you need to call

```
GET /posts/<id>/meta
```

http://wp-api.org/#posts_retrieve-meta-for-a-post

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) instead of WP REST API